# Changing certain column type to date from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` in which I want to change certain columns type to `date` from `datetime`:

```
field   category    2022-01-10 00:00:00     2022-01-17 00:00:00     2022-01-24 00:00:00
A       10          500                     700                     500
B       15          60                      70                      50
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
field   category    2022-01-10      2022-01-17      2022-01-24
A       10          500             700             500
B       15          60              70              50
```

Because during concat with other `df` the column type changes from `2021-11-19` to `2021-11-19 00:00:00`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677850/change-dataframe-column-names-from-string-format-to-datetime) I tried::

```
df.loc[:,pd.to_datetime('2022-01-10 00:00:00') : pd.to_datetime('2022-06-20 00:00:00')].columns = 
                                                 pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,pd.to_datetime('2022-01-10 00:00:00') : 
                                                 pd.to_datetime('2022-06-20 00:00:00')].columns)
                                                 .strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But this does not change the type of the column which I cant understand why because

```
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,pd.to_datetime('2022-01-10 00:00:00') : pd.to_datetime('2022-06-20 00:00:00')].columns).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Return:

```
Index(['2022-01-10', '2022-01-17', '2022-01-24')]
```

Comment: It looks like you have column headers here, which are different from the column type, can you provide an example of the data **before** `concat`?

Comment: does the other df also contain datetime column headers?

Comment: Good spot, other `df` conains string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your column index you mix string ('field' and 'category') and timestamp (other columns) so your column index is an `Index` not a `DatetimeIndex`.

```
>>> df.columns
Index([            'field',          'category', 2022-01-10 00:00:00,
       2022-01-17 00:00:00, 2022-01-24 00:00:00],
      dtype='object')

>>> [type(c) for c in df.columns]
[str,
 str,
 pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp,
 pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp,
 pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp]
```

The default string representation of `Timestamp` is `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` while the default representation of each value of a `DatetimeIndex` can be `YYYY-mm-dd` only (if possible).

To get the date format, you have to cast your `Timestamp` to string.

Answer (score 0):

Given that, the specific column type is datetime.
You can use the dt.date from pandas to keep only the date.
Please, look at the example below.

```
dates_only = df["datetime"].dt.date
```